# Dynamically adding/removing named hosts from k8s ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I'm setting up a k8s cluster on GKE.  A wildcard DNS `*.server.com` will point to a Ingress controller.  Internally to the cluster, there will be webserver pods, each exposing a unique service.  The Ingress controller will use the server name to route to the various services.

Servers will be created and destroyed on a nearly daily basis.  I'd like to know if there's a way to add and remove a named server from the ingress controller without editing the whole list of named servers.

Comment: I guess you are planning to make use of an ingress resource that redirect the traffic to different services depending on the path. When you add a new service you want to add as well a new "path" to the ingress resource and you would like to know the best way to do it?

Comment: I considered using a `kubectl patch` to do this, but it appears that the `patchStrategy` for ingress is `replace`.  I tried to add the new host to the existing list, but it replaced the existing list.

Comment: The GKE documentation says:

_Whenever any HTTP(S) load balancer is configured through Ingress, you must not manually change or update the configuration of the HTTP(S) load balancer. That is, you must not edit any of the load balancer's components, including target proxies, URL maps, and backend services. Any changes that you make are overwritten by GKE._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears like you're planning to host multiple domain names on a single Load Balancer (==single `Ingress` resource). If not, this answer doesn't apply.

You can do this by configuring `Ingress` with a long list of domain names like:

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: cats.server.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: cats
          servicePort: 8080
  - host: dogs.server.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: dogs
          servicePort: 8080
  - [...]
```

If that's your intention, **there's no way of doing this without editing this whole list** and applying it to the cluster every time.

You can build a tool to construct this manifest file, then apply the changes. The Ingress controller is smart enough that existing domains will not see a downtime if they're still on the list.

However the domains you removed from the list will also be removed from the URL Map of the load balancer and hence stop accepting the traffic.

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of domains you can add to the manifest file? Say I have a thousand domains. Would I just list a thousand domains on that file?

Comment: You should read the limitations of ingress-gce and Google Cloud HTTPS Load Balancer.

Comment: Here you can find information about limits:
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress?hl=ru#limitations

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to add a rule to an ingress by executing the following patch:

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/spec/rules/-",
    "value": {
      "host": "<HOST>",
      "http": {
        "paths": [
          {
            "path": "/*",
            "backend": {
              "serviceName": "<SERVICE_NAME>",
              "servicePort": <PORT>
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

```sh
kubectl patch ingress ${INGRESS_NAME} --type json -p "$(cat patch.json)"
```

But I cant find the solution to remove it. What I tried is the follwoing patch;

```
[
  {
    "op": "remove",
    "path": '{.spec.rules[?(@.host=="<HOST>")]}'
  }
]
```

But I just get the error 'The  "" is invalid' back from kubectl

Whats wrong with it?
I followed the jsonPath syntax from https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/